# Reading csv file from specific row

Tags: python

I am trying to pull data when "X" is found, and get everything from that row to the end. My code is only giving me the row below to the end. Is there a way to include the row with "X"?

```
a = []
with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
        for i,line in enumerate(fp):
            if "X" in line:
                #print (i, line)
                for line in fp:
                    a.append(line.split(' '))
                    print(a)
```

Comment: Just append the current row as well? Before the second loop, just do another `a.append(line.split(' '))`.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ cat file.csv
line 1
line 2
line 3
line X
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

You can use [itertools dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
import itertools as it

with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
    a=[line.strip() for line in it.dropwhile(lambda l: 'X' not in l, fp)]
```

Result:

```
>>> a
['line X', 'line 5', 'line 6', 'line 7']
```

If you want to use `enumerate` on the entire file, you can have an object that will maintain a `True` or `False` state after a test. Commonly called a FlipFlop, it is useful for finding a mark in file while only reading the file line-by-line:

```
class FlipFlop: 
    def __init__(self, start_state, func):
        self.call=func
        self.state = start_state
    def __call__(self, st):
        if self.call(st): self.state=not self.state
        return self.state

with open(fn) as f_in:
    ff=FlipFlop(False, lambda s: 'X' in s)
    x_and_after=[(i, line.strip()) for i, line in enumerate(f_in) if ff(line)]
```

Result:

```
>>> x_and_after
[(3, 'line X'), (4, 'line 5'), (5, 'line 6'), (6, 'line 7')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if 'X' in line:
            print('FOUND X [{}]: {}'.format(i, line))
            a.append(line.split(' '))
            for j, line in enumerate(fp, start=i+1):
                print('FOUND after X [{}]: {}'.format(j, line))
                a.append(line.split(' '))

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second loop over the open file is picking up on the line after you find 'X'.  You can add a "flag" and remove the inner loop:

```
a = []
after_x = False

with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
    for i,line in enumerate(fp):
        after_x = after_x or "X" in line
        if after_x:
            a.append(line.split(' '))
            print(a)
```